# How to determine *nix file permissions?

Tags: permissions

Let's say the output of `id` is

`uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)`

And I have a file which have generated the following output using `ll`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 202 Jun  5 12:28 config.txt`

That is, the group ID of the file doesn't match mine, but I am the owner of the file.
My question is, do I have write access to the given file?
Sorry that being noobish but I am really new, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: As the owner of the file, you can change the file permission
>   (regardless to the current file permission)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 202 Jun  5 12:28 config.txt
```

In this case, the owner of the file (`user`) has `rw-` permission
which means that the owner has read/write permission to the file.

However, if the owner of the file has no access permission to the file, as the owner, he can grant himself permission to the file using `chmod`, for example:

```
chmod u+rwx config.txt
```

- u - the user owned the file
- rwx - read/write/execution

More info:

- [chmod manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)
- [Wikipedia chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)
- [How to Set File Permissions Using chmod](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html)
- [Modify File Permissions with chmod](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod)

Answer (score 0):

The second, third and fourth characters in the permission field determine the permissions to a given file. In this case, these are -`rw-`r--r--. So the user named `user` has read and write access to the file `config.txt`, but the executable flag is off.